# Which settings do I need to change to install packages from another private repo in Github actions?

Tags: npm, github-actions, yarnpkg

We've got a monorepo (call it `A`) that has several packages published to `npm.pkg.github.com`. I just started another repo (`B`), and would like to pull in one of the packages from `A`, but I'm getting a `403` during the GH Actions build process. Both repos are under the same organization. Here's the relevant bit of my action:

```yaml
      - name: authorize github npm
        run: echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" >> .npmrc

      - run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

The `.npmrc` exists (and is checked in), and should be right:

```
@<org-name>:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

I can "fix" the problem by adding a PAT to the repository secrets and using that instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN` but I'd rather not.

Is there something I need to change in the settings for repo `A` to let its packages be accessible from repo `B`?

Comment: I can't think of a way around using a PAT.

Comment: The default `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't have such access to other repos.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token